# Как отсортировать массив по его элементам js

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, интернет-магазин

Я делаю интернет магазин, товаров выходит много, и для этого мне нужна сортировка.

Это сам массив в котором хранятся данные о продукте.

```
const CATALOG = [
    {
        id: 'el1',
        name: 'ЗОЛОТОЙ ШАМПУНЬ',
        img: '../../main/Estel/img/estel-prima-blond/ЗОЛОТОЙ ШАМПУНЬ.webp',
        quantity: 1,
        price: 450,
        productType: 'shampoo',
    },
    {
        id: 'el2',
        name: 'СЕРЕБРИСТЫЙ ШАМПУНЬ',
        img: '../../main/Estel/img/estel-prima-blond/СЕРЕБРИСТЫЙ ШАМПУНЬ.webp',
        price: 900,
        quantity: 1,
        productType: 'shampoo',
    },
    {
        id: 'el3',
        name: 'СЕРЕБРИСТЫЙ БАЛЬЗАМ',
        img: '../../main/Estel/img/estel-prima-blond/СЕРЕБРИСТЫЙ БАЛЬЗАМ.webp',
        price: 450,
        quantity: 1,
        productType: 'balsam',
    },
    {
        id: 'el4',
        name: 'СЕРЕБРИСТАЯ МАСКА',
        img: '../../main/Estel/img/estel-prima-blond/СЕРЕБРИСТАЯ МАСКА.webp',
        price: 650,
        quantity: 1,
        productType: 'mask',
    }];
```

Это функция onclick, при нажатии должна сортировать именно тот товар, у которого в элементе массива написан productType: 'shampoo', но не работает.

```
function shampooFun() {
    return CATALOG = CATALOG.filter((element)=>{return element['productType'] === 'shampoo';});
}
```

Далее КАТАЛОГ должен сделать выводы разными способами, но ничего не вышло.

Вот визуальная часть для общего понимания, [image: изоброжение]

Answer (score 1):

```
    function shampooFun() {
        return CATALOG.filter((element)=>element.productType === 'shampoo');
    }
    shampooFun()
```

Comment: Ошибки нет, спасибо, но у меня далее через forEach идет отображение элементов, по идеи когда в возвращаю CATALOG, он же должен быть только с shampoo, а он не изменяется, и так же когда я вызываю function shampooFun, ошибки нет, но ничего и не изменяется, работает только если я ручками пишу otherFun(CATALOG).forEach(({ id, name, price, img}) => {, (тут я к каталогу написал otherFun)

Comment: let filter_CATALOG = []

function shampooFun() {
       filter_CATALOG = CATALOG.filter((element)=>element.productType === 'shampoo');
        return  filter_CATALOG
    }
    shampooFun()

теперь в filter_CATALOG будет то, что отфильтровано, а сама CATALOG не изменяется, это вам и не нужно

Answer (score 0):

```js
const CATALOG = [
    {
        id: 'el1',
        name: 'ЗОЛОТОЙ ШАМПУНЬ',
        img: '../../main/Estel/img/estel-prima-blond/ЗОЛОТОЙ ШАМПУНЬ.webp',
        quantity: 1,
        price: 450,
        productType: 'shampoo',
    },
    {
        id: 'el2',
        name: 'СЕРЕБРИСТЫЙ ШАМПУНЬ',
        img: '../../main/Estel/img/estel-prima-blond/СЕРЕБРИСТЫЙ ШАМПУНЬ.webp',
        price: 900,
        quantity: 1,
        productType: 'shampoo',
    },
    {
        id: 'el3',
        name: 'СЕРЕБРИСТЫЙ БАЛЬЗАМ',
        img: '../../main/Estel/img/estel-prima-blond/СЕРЕБРИСТЫЙ БАЛЬЗАМ.webp',
        price: 450,
        quantity: 1,
        productType: 'balsam',
    },
    {
        id: 'el4',
        name: 'СЕРЕБРИСТАЯ МАСКА',
        img: '../../main/Estel/img/estel-prima-blond/СЕРЕБРИСТАЯ МАСКА.webp',
        price: 650,
        quantity: 1,
        productType: 'mask',
    }];

function shampooFun(CATALOG) {
    return CATALOG.filter((element)=>{return element['productType'] === 'shampoo';});
}

console.log(shampooFun(CATALOG));
```

Comment: Ошибки нет, спасибо, но у меня далее через forEach идет отображение элементов, по идеи когда в возвращаю CATALOG, он же должен быть только с shampoo, а он не изменяется, и так же когда я вызываю function shampooFun, ошибки нет, но ничего и не изменяется, работает только если я ручками пишу otherFun(CATALOG).forEach(({ id, name, price, img}) => {, (тут я к каталогу написал otherFun)